# How to develop a Facebook application that receives realtime data from the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Facebook application, and I want to use [realtime updates from the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). The application will run on a server with a globally accessible URL, but during the development I run it on a local server, and I don't even have a globally accessible IP address.

Is there a way to receive those realtime updates to my local-host server during development?

Comment: try use a service like No-IP or DynDNS to assign a domain name that will always point to your local network.

Comment: Actually, my problem is not the DNS, but the lack of global access to my IP.